# How to use selected items from a listview in multiple views

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm, data-binding

I have a separate view that contains an observable collection and would like to use the selected item from the collection in another view (MainView). Can anyone tell me how to implement the property change in the MainView?

The Main Window:

```
<Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainWindowViewModel x:Name="mainWindowViewModel"/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <view:OwnerListViewModel x:Key="OwnerList"/>
    </Window.Resources>


            <TextBlock Height="25" Margin="0 5 0 0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding 
                       PersonModel.FirstName}" ></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Height="25" Margin="0 5 0 0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding 
                       PersonModel.SurName}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></TextBlock>
```

In MainWindowViewModel:

```
 private OwnerListViewModel OwnerListViewModel { get; } = new OwnerListViewModel();

        public Owner PersonModel
        {
            get { return OwnerListViewModel.PersonModel; }
            set { OwnerListViewModel.PersonModel = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
        }
```

In the LoadOwner Window, i created the ListView:

```
 <Window.DataContext>
        <view:OwnerListViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
        <ListView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonsView}" SelectedValue="{Binding 
         PersonModel, Mode=TwoWay}">

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectionChangedCmd}" 
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding 
                                           ElementName=PersonListWindow}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="auto">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>                            
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="0 0 5 0" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Text="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                         Text="{Binding SurName}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

My OwnerListViewModel:

Here I am not sure how to implement the property change. Using an asynchronous task, or are there other options? I would be very grateful for a tip!

```
public OwnerListViewModel()
        {
            Persons = new ObservableCollection<Owner>();

            var sample1 = new Owner()
            {
                FirstName = "SampleFirstName1",
                SurName = "SampleLastname1",
                Street = "SampleStreet1",
                HouseNumber = 987,
                AdditionalAdress = "",
                ZipCode = 99999,
                City = "SampleCity1"
            };
            AddOwner(sample1);

            PersonsView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Persons);
            PersonsView.CurrentChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                OnPropertyChanged(() => PersonModel);
            };

            SelectionChangedCmd = new RelayCommand<Window>(this.closeWindow);
        }

        #region listProperties

        private ObservableCollection<Owner> Persons { get; }

        public ICollectionView PersonsView { get; set; }

        public Owner PersonModel
        {
            get => PersonsView.CurrentItem as Owner;
            set
            {
                PersonsView.MoveCurrentTo(value);
                OnPropertyChanged();

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created different objects of OwnerListViewModel. One way is deleting this code from 2 views:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <view:OwnerListViewModel x:Key="OwnerList"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and bind datacontext in view codebehind:

```
var ownerListViewModel = new OwnerListViewModel();
LoadOwnerWindow.DataContext = ownerListViewModel;   
MainView.DataContext = ownerListViewModel.PersonModel;
```

Also you can use IoC to bind view models.

Also, the other way is using WPF messenger to send changed owner as a message from LoadOwnerWindow to MainView

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to set the data context directly in the main window:

```
 <TextBox Height="25" Margin="0 5 0 0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" DataContext="{Binding OwnerListViewModel.SelectedItem}" Text="{Binding FirstName}" ></TextBox>
            <TextBox Height="25" Margin="0 5 0 0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding OwnerListViewModel.SelectedItem}" Text="{Binding SurName}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"></TextBox>
```